# Wrong symbols when sending Request to PHP Script

Tags: php, ios, string, swift, hash

From my app I send a request to a PHP script on website.

In my app I configure a string which is something like this: `name=John&pass=apricot&constKey=12345`.

Then I use hash on that string and receive something like this: `blablabla25`. Now it is localKey.

And then I send the final string `name=John&pass=apricot&localKey=blablabla25` to PHP script.

In my PHP script I take this string except localKey (`name=John&pass=apricot`) and add constKey, which stored in PHP file. Again I get the string `name=John&pass=apricot&constKey=12345`. That's good.

Then I hash that string and compare it with the localKey, which is `blablabla25`. If keys are equal, then everything is okay. In most cases it works fine.

But sometimes I send, for example, this: `text=I'm happy.That's why I'm dancing`. And I receive error, because when I hash string in Swift it looks the same way. And when I hash that string in PHP - apostrophe is replaced with something like this - `\\\'`

Here are parts of my code for Swift and PHP files.

```
post = post + "key=\(sign)"
    post = post.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
    post = post.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "%2B")

    let postData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    let postLength = "\(postData?.length)"

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/admin.php")!
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)

    request.URL = url
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = postData
```

and PHP file

```
$key = NULL;
if (isset($POST['key'])) $key = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['key']);
if (!$key)
    {
        exit();
    }

    $login = NULL;
    $pass = NULL;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $pars = array();

    foreach ($_POST as $par => $val)
    {
        $pars[$par] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
    }

    ksort($pars);

    $str = "";

    foreach ($pars as $pr => $vl)
    {
        if ($pr != 'key') $str .= $pr . '=' . $vl;
    }

    $str .= genkey;

    $sign = md5($str);

    if (strcmp($key, $sign)  !== 0)
    {
        retError(err_unknown, 'Unknown error');
        exit();
    }
```

I know that MD5 isn't good today, but that's not the point of the question.

**PHP updated code**

```
    $key = NULL;
    if (isset($_POST['key'])) $key = $_POST['key'];

    if (!$key)
    {
        exit();
    }

    $login = NULL;

    $pass = NULL;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $pars = array();

    foreach ($_POST as $par => $val)
    {
        $pars[$par] = $val;
    }

    ksort($pars);

    $str = "";

    foreach ($pars as $pr => $vl)
    {
        if ($pr != 'key') $str .= $pr . '=' . $vl;
    }

    $str .= genkey;

    $sign = md5($str);

    if (strcmp($key, $sign)  !== 0)
    {
        exit();
    }
```

String, that i send to PHP script:

```
'Suggs
'H
Fgdfh'dg'hd'hgd
```

String, that is in PHP:

```
\\'Suggs\n\\'H\nFgdfh\\'dg\\'hd\\'hgd
```

So, new line is `\n` and apostrophe is `\\'`
And when i hash string in swift there is no `\n` and `\\'`. That's why hashes are different.
I can simply remove new lines and apostrophe from the string, but it is not the best solution, i suppose

Comment: Might be helpful to add what version PHP you're working with.

Comment: yes, you are right. Next time i will :)

Comment: On that note, you are really in need of an upgrade. PHP 5.3 has been end of life for 2 years now!

Comment: it wasn't me who created server side, now i need to work with this, soon i will try to move to next php version. U are totally right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `magic_quotes_gpc` on in your PHP configuration (it's on by default in PHP < 5.4), you need to call `stripslashes` on any variables in `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: i'll try soon. But i suppose, that is the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. Next time i will add version of PHP, that I use. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping that string too fast (it's reason of chnaging ' to \'). btw. just use some [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) mysql_ extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0

UPDATE code to cut key=xxx part from query

```
$dataArray=$_POST;


if (isset($dataArray['key'])){
    unset($dataArray['key']);
}

echo http_build_query($dataArray);
```

Comment: if i don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` and just write this: `$pars[$par] =$val;` then i get `\'`, but it is still not the same as `'`

Comment: also i've moved from mysql to mysqli, but still no progress(

Comment: can You post your code after changes ? also check this line:

if (isset($POST['key'])) $key = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['key']);

Comment: I've updated the question. I've added exact text which brake my app

Comment: Ok one more question can you post exactly output of var_dump($_POST) ? I can't tell too much about swift but for php it's looking good I think, also if you want to cut only key=xxxx part from query string You can use something like that code in my updated answer.